# Date string while creating Excel CSV File outputs ###### ##### instead of the value

Tags: php, excel, csv

I wanna create a simple CSV file without `PHPExcel`

I have the following code:

```
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="Bestellungen_Export.csv";');
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        foreach ($list as $fields) {
            fputcsv($f, $fields, ';');
        }
```

now I have a datetime string `29.10.2012 12:20:02 (d.m.Y H:i:s)`. Now its inserted into the excel and looks like that: `##########`. Obviously Excel doesn't find the correct date format for that string. If I double click the `column`, the correct value is displayed. Now my questions:

- What is the exact error here that it displays ########
- How can I make it show the correct date?

Comment: ## represent not enough width to show the data , just change the columns width in excel

Comment: There is no error. You just need to change the width of column.

Comment: @RioRuslan Ah, so is it possible to change that inside my PHP script? Cause otherwise it will look exactly the same for the next user who opens it.

Comment: No it isn't possible with a csv file: a csv file contains only data, no formatting or styling or column width settings or anything beyond the raw data.... if you need that, then you need to use a format which does support styling, etc such as native BIFF (xls) or OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSV-File is a text file witch contains only text in comma separated format. When you open your CSV and you see only `###` in a column, the width is too small.

You can't solve that problem without building a Excel-file with style informations. So if you have to declare the with or the type of the column you have to use `PHPExcel` and specify them for that col.